# Kotlin / value passing to List<>()

Tags: kotlin

I have a question in `List<Contact>()` I'm asked to pass `init` and `size`. I'm not sure if it's obligated to pass it as in my following tutorial `ArrayList<String>()` was empty, maybe it's because I was using `List<>`? Also, it doesn't recognize `lowercase()` and `add()` is it also related to `List<>`?

**Code Snippet**

```kotlin
val contacts = remember { DataProvider.contactList }
var filteredContacts: List<Contact>
val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
LazyColumn(
    ...
) {
    val searchText = textVal.value.text
    filteredContacts = if (searchText.isEmpty()){
        contacts
    }
    else{
        val resultList = List<Contact>()
        for (contact in contacts) {
            if (contact.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))) {
                resultList.add(contact)
            }
        }
        resultList
    }
```

Comment: Create the list with `mutableListOf<Contact>()`.

Comment: Or better still, do it the functional way: `filter()` the contacts to give a list.  That way you get a safe read-only list, and you don't need to worry about how it's created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin, `List` has no `add` method. For that you would need to have a `MutableList`.
Regarding `lowercase` method, this is available for `String`s. You are trying to apply that to a `Contact` object, which I guess has no `lowercase` method.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I want to make search bar in my app, what type of List or Array would you advice to use it receiving data from the object (with id=..., name=...,description=...)?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question. What object are you talking about? Can you explain your use case in another way? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, as I have mentioned before I want to make search bar in my app. At the moment I am using my "DataProvider" obj to get certain item data like (with id=..., name=...,description=...). But I struggle comparing the data from  "DataProvider"  List<> and filteredList which is MutableList as you adviced. How should I convert propertly my "DataProvider"  List<>, so it could be compared to filteredList  as an example?

Comment: Ok, that is a different topic. I would suggest you create a new question with all the needed details (including `DataProvider` and `Contact` classes) so that we can help you further.